# Why doesn't DropCreateDatabaseAlways drop the database when the model changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a model with one entity:

```
   namespace TestMigration
{
    public class BlogContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int FollowersCount { get; set; }
        //public int BloggerAge { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The Initializer class:

```
 public class DataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BlogContext context)
        {
            var blogs = new List<Blog>
            {
                new Blog {FollowersCount=456, Name="ABC", Url="abc.com" },
                new Blog {FollowersCount=789, Name="DEF", Url="def.com" },
                new Blog {FollowersCount=246, Name="GHI", Url="ghi.com" },
                new Blog {FollowersCount=135, Name="JKL", Url="jkl.com" },
                new Blog {FollowersCount=258, Name="MNO", Url="mno.com" }
            };
            blogs.ForEach(b => context.Blogs.Add(b));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Main Method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DataInitializer());
            using (var db = new BlogContext())
            {
                //db.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "KOLP" });
                //db.SaveChanges();
                foreach (var blog in db.Blogs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n*****({blog.BlogId})*****");
                    Console.WriteLine("blog.Name: " + blog.Name);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

To understand the role of `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` I deleted a property from this entity(`Blog`), and when I run the application, it throws this error:

> There is already an object named 'Blogs' in the database.

Shouldn't it drop the database at any case, and then recreate it from the presented model?

Comment: can you show the other configurations also?

Comment: is this `EF 6` or ?

Comment: I updated my code. I use the latest version 6.1.3

Comment: you never actually set the initializer of your dbContext. To be fair, you didn't even specify a connection string, you also didn't define the constructor (which SHOULD set the initializer at least).

Comment: I didn't set a connection string explicitly because it will set it up automatically. 
Could you please explain further in an answer?

Comment: The initializer works, if the schema doesn't change, and it will drop the data and recreate it from the `Seed` method, thus, no need to set the initializer in the constructor

Comment: I do believe the seed method only works because you called the code to configure it for your BlogContext, but the database initializer is still the default one. Also, I've never seen DbContext work without connection string/ connection, how would it set up automatically?

Comment: It will use the DbContext class name as the database name, and will default to using  LocalDB. if you run the application, you can see it from SQL server object explorer window created for you